# tkinter: How to make timer run in a background

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, time, timer

I have a game - catching coins into a bowl. However, one of the criteria is to make it limited by entering time in seconds - how long will the game last. The time user enters is from `tkinter.Entry`, and I have no idea how to execute a timer and a function at the same time. Code progress:

```
import tkinter, random, time
from threading import Thread

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("Dukaty")

canvas = tkinter.Canvas(window, height = 400, width = 800)
canvas.pack()


timeLabel = tkinter.Label(text = "Time:", font = "Helvetica 15")
timeLabel.pack()
timeEntry = tkinter.Entry(bd = 1)
timeEntry.pack()
mistakesLabel = tkinter.Label(text = "Allowed mistakes:", font = "Helvetica 15")
mistakesLabel.pack()
mistakesEntry = tkinter.Entry(bd = 1)
mistakesEntry.pack()

timeEntry.insert(0, "0")
mistakesEntry.insert(0, "0")

speed = 250
score = 0
mistakes = 0
allowedTime = ""


def countdown(t):
    while t:
        mins, secs = divmod(t, 60)
        timer = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)
        allowedTime = timer
        print(allowedTime)
        time.sleep(1)
        t -= 1

    print("Time's up!")


def timedGame():
    time = int(timeEntry.get())
    canvas.after(time * 1000)
    end()

def movingCoin():
    global speed, score, mistakes, allowedTime
    time = int(timeEntry.get())
    coin = canvas.create_image(random.randint(15, 585), 18, image=coinImg, tags="coin")

    canvas.create_text(700, 50, text = str(score), font = "Helvetica 20", fill = "green", tags = "score")
    canvas.create_text(700, 80, text = str(mistakes), font = "Helvetica 20", fill = "red", tags = "mistakes")
    # ENDLESS

    if timeEntry.get() == "0" and mistakesEntry.get() == "0":
        while True:
            if canvas.coords(coin)[1] < 360:
                canvas.move(coin, 0, 5)
                canvas.after(speed)
                canvas.update()
            elif canvas.coords(coin)[1] >= 360 and (canvas.coords(coin)[0] > (canvas.coords(bowl)[0] - 40) and canvas.coords(coin)[0] < (canvas.coords(bowl)[0] + 40)):
                canvas.delete("score")
                score += 1
                canvas.create_text(700, 50, text=str(score), font="Helvetica 20", fill="green", tags="score")
                canvas.delete(coin)
                coin = canvas.create_image(random.randint(15, 585), 18, image=coinImg, tags="coin")
                speed -= 10
            else:
                canvas.delete("mistakes")
                mistakes += 1
                canvas.create_text(700, 80, text=str(mistakes), font="Helvetica 20", fill="red", tags="mistakes")
                canvas.delete(coin)
                coin = canvas.create_image(random.randint(15, 585), 18, image=coinImg, tags="coin")
                speed -= 10

    # TIME - not done yet

    elif timeEntry.get() != "0" and mistakesEntry.get() == "0":
        while str(allowedTime) != "00:00":
            if canvas.coords(coin)[1] < 360:
                canvas.move(coin, 0, 5)
                canvas.after(speed)
                canvas.update()
            elif canvas.coords(coin)[1] >= 360 and (canvas.coords(coin)[0] > (canvas.coords(bowl)[0] - 40) and canvas.coords(coin)[0] < (canvas.coords(bowl)[0] + 40)):
                score += 1
                print(score)
                canvas.delete(coin)
                coin = canvas.create_image(random.randint(15, 585), 18, image=coinImg, tags="coin")
                speed -= 10
            else:
                mistakes += 1
                print(mistakes)
                canvas.delete(coin)
                coin = canvas.create_image(random.randint(15, 585), 18, image=coinImg, tags="coin")
                speed -= 10



    # MISTAKES

    elif timeEntry.get() == "0" and mistakesEntry != "0":

        allowedMistakes = int(mistakesEntry.get())
        print("Allowed mistakes: " + str(allowedMistakes))

        while True:
            if canvas.coords(coin)[1] < 360:
                canvas.move(coin, 0, 5)
                canvas.after(speed)
                canvas.update()
            elif canvas.coords(coin)[1] >= 360 and (canvas.coords(coin)[0] > (canvas.coords(bowl)[0] - 40) and canvas.coords(coin)[0] < (canvas.coords(bowl)[0] + 40)):
                canvas.delete("score")
                score += 1
                canvas.create_text(700, 50, text=str(score), font="Helvetica 20", fill="green", tags="score")
                canvas.delete(coin)
                coin = canvas.create_image(random.randint(15, 585), 18, image=coinImg, tags="coin")
                speed -= 10
            else:
                if allowedMistakes > mistakes:
                    canvas.delete("mistakes")
                    mistakes += 1
                    canvas.create_text(700, 80, text=str(mistakes), font="Helvetica 20", fill="red", tags="mistakes")
                    canvas.delete(coin)
                    coin = canvas.create_image(random.randint(15, 585), 18, image=coinImg, tags="coin")
                    speed -= 10

                elif allowedMistakes == mistakes:
                    print("ending the program")
                    break


def end():
    window.destroy()

def tap():
    Thread(target=countdown(int(timeEntry.get()))).start()
    Thread(target=movingCoin).start()

endButton = tkinter.Button(text = "End", command = end)
endButton.pack(side = "right")
startButton = tkinter.Button(text = "Start", command = tap)
startButton.pack(side = "left")


window.mainloop()
```

What this does, is that it starts the timer, and when it comes to end, THEN it executes the movingCoin function.

What I want to achieve is to make the timer start (when in Entry is value greater than 0) and at the same time execute the movingCoin - which then drops to the time section and the while breaks when the time is up.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I hope it works for you, cheer.

```
import time
# time.time() return in second
game_duration = float(input('duration: ')) + time.time() 

game_is_running = True

while game_is_running:
    if game_duration == time.time(): # this means: if now equal to game_duration
        game_is_running = False

# note: it is quite critical where you place time.time()
```

## One more example:

```
# I used the following technique to build an explosion animation for 30 seconds, then it will do something else.
class Explosion(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, center):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = explosion_animation[0]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = center
        self.frame = 0
        self.last_update = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        self.duration = 30


    def update(self):
        now = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        if now - self.last_update > self.duration:
            self.last_update = now
            self.frame += 1
            if self.frame == len(explosion_animation):
                self.kill()
            else:
                center = self.rect.center
                self.image = explosion_animation[self.frame]
                self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
                self.rect.center = center
```

Comment: I would replace the equality condition with: game_duration  <  time.time() because you have no guarantee that the call to time.time() will fall exactly on the predefined time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method

> window.after(1000,<function_name>)

It means the function call after 1 sec. If you are use recursion with this method then you can create timer.

Comment: Yes, but the command .after() stops the whole program and after some time it executes the function. What I need is to start the timer, which does not interrupt the second function called at the same time - movingCoin - the actual game mechanics.

Comment: But, In my case it works. I thinks it can help you.   https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/create-stopwatch-using-python/amp/